# how to run an if condition with tfileList nb_file variable in Talend

Tags: java, if-statement, talend

I have a `tfilelist` scanning a repertory with several `.cfg` files.
these cfg files contain variables like country, store, filter, email and so on.

These variables are needed for my next `tFileList` in order to scan the right repertory depending the country & store and send an email to the right person if no files are found.

```
tFileList (no error generation) --iterate--> tJava --iterate--> tfileCopy

                                      |

                                      |if nofilefound

                                    tSendMail
```

The code of my tJava is:

```
boolean nofilefound = false ;


int ff;
ff = ((Integer)globalMap.get("tFileList_2_NB_FILE")) ;
String c = null ;
c = Integer.toString(ff) ;

if (c != null)
{ 

    System.out.println(jobName + " * " + context.pays + ": files: " + c);   
} 

else if (c == null) {
     nofilefound = true ;
     System.out.println(jobName + " * " + context.pays + "=> envoi email");
}
```

This is not working, the if is false and tsendmail not executed.
I can't use "on component error" because it stops the loop when no files are found.

please help me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it seems i have to put the `if` trigger from `tFileList` to `tSendMail` in order to solve the problem,
with the condition `((Integer)globalMap.get("tFileList_2_NB_FILE")) < 1`

Answer (score -1):

You can just activate the "Generate error if no file found" checkbox and link `tFileList` as `on component error` to `tSendEmail`.

it will be `tFilelist--on component error--->tSendEmail`.